# How to sort a View according to contextual filters?

Tags: views

I have a view that filters nodes by a contextual filter that allows multiple values. So it gets a list of node IDs like `234, 235, 210, 56, 78`.
Is it possible to sort the result of this view according to the order of the given IDs?
I tried to achieve that by deleting all sort criteria, but this leads to an arbitrary order of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Views Arguments Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arguments_extras) module (for Drupal 7) seems to do what you are looking for. According to the module page, it provides the following:

> **Argument Order Sort**
>
> a sort handler, that allows for the order of items to be based on
>   their order in a multi-value argument

This particular component is ported to Drupal 8: [Views Argument Order Sort](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_arg_order_sort):

> Using this module will give you a new sort type with a variety of
>   options where you can choose what field to apply the argument values
>   to for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a contextual filter with multiple values, views generates a query that has something like this `WHERE (node_field_data.nid IN('72586', '60952', '72516', '50611', '60328', '49852', '49819', '49816', '60609', '49834', '60220', '50841'))`

Views is doing everything properly, however SQL will effectively sort it from lowest to highest integer.

You need to alter the query to something like this here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858828/sql-where-in-sort-by-order-of-the-list

to achieve the sort you want.